# Sorting arrays and arrays of arrays using a key parameter

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array of students which is fetched in a variable $arraytosort and looks  like

```
       array(5027) { [0]=> array(5) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#22 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58131c7799fbad4c1d000202" } ["fullname"]=> string(19) "David Robert Lara" ["firstmiddle"]=> string(12) "David Robert" ["firstlast"]=> string(14) "David Lara" ["student"]=> array(50) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#23 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58131c7799fbad4c1d000202" } ["student_id"]=> float(2) ["registration_temp_perm_no"]=> string(1) "1" ["roll_no"]=> float(1) ["admission_date"]=> string(10) "01/07/2016" ["first_name"]=> string(7) "David" ["middle_name"]=> string(4) "Robert" ["last_name"]=> string(6) "Lara" ["dob"]=> string(10) "12/03/1981" ["gender"]=> string(6) "Female" ["blood_group"]=> string(2) "A+" ["birth_place"]=> string(11) "Sadar Bazar" ["nationality"]=> string(6) "Indian" ["language"]=> string(7) "English" ["religion"]=> string(8) "Agnostic" ["address_line1"]=> string(20) "4148 Hazelcrest Hill" ["address_line2"]=> string(20) "22883 Memorial Place" ["city"]=> string(11) "Sadar Bazar" ["state"]=> string(13) "Uttar Pradesh" ["pincode"]=> string(6) "190010" ["country"]=> string(5) "India" ["phone1"]=> string(10) "9039180419" ["phone2"]=> string(10) "7681559402" ["email"]=> string(24) "educianstudent@gmail.com" ["is_sms_enabled"]=> string(3) "Yes" ["is_active"]=> int(1) ["has_finished"]=> int(0) ["student_category"]=> string(1) "5" ["course"]=> string(24) "58131c7099fbad4c1d0001c2" ["Biometric_ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["siblings"]=> string(14) "Cynthia Taylor" ["guardian_name"]=> string(14) "Cynthia Taylor" ["guardian_occupation"]=> string(13) "Senior Editor" ["guardian_qualification"]=> string(20) "Research Assistant I" ["guardian_email_id"]=> string(23) "educianparent@gmail.com" ["gaurdain_contact_details"]=> string(10) "9419513603" ["guardian_relationship"]=> string(6) "Father" ["height"]=> string(3) "4.9" ["weight"]=> string(4) "34.9" ["allergies"]=> string(0) "" ["batch"]=> int(2) ["academicyear"]=> string(4) "2015" ["batchhistory"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["batchid"]=> float(2) ["academic_year"]=> string(4) "2015" ["course"]=> string(24) "58131c7099fbad4c1d0001c2" ["sequenceno"]=> int(1) ["courseId"]=> object(MongoId)#24 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58131c7099fbad4c1d0001c2" } } } ["uploads"]=> array(1) { ["profile_pic"]=> string(39) "58131c7799fbad4c1d000202schoolgirl2.jpg" } ["created_at"]=> NULL ["updated_at"]=> string(0) "" ["routearray"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["routeid"]=> int(2) ["academicyear"]=> string(4) "2016" ["current"]=> int(0) ["vehicleno"]=> string(9) "JK01S8764" ["dateofassignment"]=> string(10) "09/28/2016" } [1]=> array(5) { ["routeid"]=> int(3) ["academicyear"]=> string(4) "2016" ["current"]=> int(1) ["vehicleno"]=> string(9) "JK01S8764" ["dateofassignment"]=> string(10) "11/17/2016" } } ["HostelAlloted"]=> array(7) { ["Food Preferences"]=> string(4) "Both" ["Hostel"]=> object(MongoId)#25 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58138aee99fbade41e000031" } ["Floor"]=> string(7) "Floor_1" ["RoomNumber"]=> int(11) ["Approved"]=> string(3) "yes" ["Approved On"]=> object(MongoDate)#26 (2) { ["sec"]=> int(1472322600) ["usec"]=> int(0) } ["Academic Year"]=> string(4) "2016" } ["HostelAllotmentHistory"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["Food Preferences"]=> string(4) "Both" ["Hostel"]=> object(MongoId)#27 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58138aee99fbade41e000031" } ["Floor"]=> string(7) "Floor_1" ["RoomNumber"]=> int(11) ["Approved"]=> string(3) "yes" ["Approved On"]=> object(MongoDate)#28 (2) { ["sec"]=> int(1472322600) ["usec"]=> int(0) } ["Academic Year"]=> string(4) "2016" } } ["courseId"]=> object(MongoId)#29 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "58131c7099fbad4c1d0001c2" } } }
       ...
       ...                  
       }
```

I have written below function to sort these students on the basis of key value given in $key so that the array will contain the similar results on top/first.

```
       $sortedarray = array();
               $sortedarray = $this->multiSort(
                 $arraytosort,
                 $key,
                'fullname',
                'firstmiddle',
                'firstlast',
                'first_name',
                'middle_name',
                'last_name',
                'roll_no',
                'email'
                );

   function multiSort()
   { 
     $args = func_get_args(); 
     $c = count($args); 
     if ($c < 2) { 
          return false; 
     }

     $key= $args[1]; 

      $array = array_splice($args, 0, 1); 
      $array = $array[0];

      usort($array, function($a) use($args) { 

      $i = 0; 
      $c = count($args); 
      $cmp = 0; 
    while($cmp == 0 && $i < $c) 
    { 
        $cmp = stripos($a[$args[$i] ],$key); 
        $i++; 
    } 

    return $cmp; 
   }); 

   return $array; 
    }
```

It throws error message "Undefined variable: key".
Please help!!!

Comment: You're missing a comma after `'firstlast'` in your `multiSort()` method call.

Comment: It still throws Undefined index: student.first_name, Undefined index: student.middle_name, .... and also Undefined variable: key

Comment: That's a different error now though? That I imagine is down to not all of the elements you're sorting having a `student.first_name` index?

Comment: Yes it is now throwing the errors mentioned in the above comment

Comment: in multiSort() method you did not receives the parameters, and you can write multiSort()  method first and call that method. in the above you called first the you wrote multiSort() method.

Comment: Yes it is not able to get $key

Comment: write like,  function multiSort($param1, $param2, .....){}, like this

Comment: Actually I am trying to sort the arrays based on a $key variable and multiple feilds. I mean if $key will contain "David Robert", It should fetch all the david robert on the top/first of the array. Similarly  if $key will contain 22 then it should fetch the students with rollno 22 then others (where rollno are similar like 222 or 1222)

Comment: @rajanasekhar: if i will do like this, then how will it will dynamically fetch arguments in  $cmp = stripos($a[$args[$i] ],$key);

Comment: @rajanasekhar OP is using `func_get_args()` to get the args passed into the function - so I'm afraid that won't be the issue.

Comment: Sorry i m not getting it

Comment: I have updated my question now

Comment: @user2179026, you have to enclose `$key` into the anonymous function (pass it along with `$args` to the `use`). Now `$key` not in the scope of closure, so you get "Undefined variable: key".

Comment: can u show me how!!! I am passing it in function($a, $key). It still throws error